# Cannot load Goldenlayout library on electron app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, electron

Hi I'm trying to recreate Golden Layout angular complex application https://golden-layout.com/tutorials/angular-complex.html as a electron application, so basically I just did the quick start example of electron http://electron.atom.io/docs/latest/tutorial/quick-start/ and did all the logic of golden layout on my index.html but it send to me this error:

jQuery is missing as dependency for GoldenLayout. Please either expose $ on GoldenLayout's scope (e.g. window) or add "jquery" to your paths when using RequireJS/AMD

Comment: Did you actually add jquery like it's suggesting, and as is suggested first thing in Golden Layout's [getting started guide](https://golden-layout.com/tutorials/getting-started.html)?

Comment: yes I did but that didn´t work, it seems that you can add the conf `code node-integration : false in order to get this working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined) you need to load jquery in the following way (before including golden-layout):

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./path/to/jquery.js');</script>
```

If I understand correctly, the issue occurs because jquery 'detects' that it is running in a requireJS environment and load `$` and `jQuery` in `modules` (not `window`)

Comment: You can also use requirejs more explicitly to load jQuery by following this guide https://golden-layout.com/tutorials/requirejs.html