# AngularJs 1.x not working with SemanticUI.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, semantic-ui

When i try to use AngularJs with SemanticUI.js, the console says

> Uncaught ReferenceError : jQuery is not defined

Here is my example of implementation :

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- I'm head of the document -->
</head>
<body>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/semantic.min.js"></script>

<!-- My own script place right here -->

</body>
</html>
```

Am i doing the right way? I've tried to swap the script position, but my code still doesn't work.

I think the problem in the semantic.min.js, maybe the $ has been replaced by angular or something that i don't know, because when i try to remove the semantic.min.js, no one appears in the console.

I have also try another solution that i've found in stackoverflow, but yes, it still not works.

Only additional information :

```
AngularJs version 1.5.5
JQuery version 2.2.4
Semantic version 2.1.8
```

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Can you open the jQuery file in browser from link in browser source code?

Comment: @charlietfl yes i can open it.

Comment: Where is your own code being placed? Is it before jQuery.js?

Comment: How about your own code? is it placed before the jquery ref or after? It seems to be a problem with jquery rather than angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, sorry, my bad.

I found the problem, it's not the jQuery problem, it's Electron problem.

Because my project use Electron, so the solution is right here :

> [Electron : jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's jQuery problem.

That error can only be caused by one of three things:

1. Your JavaScript file is not being properly loaded into your page
2. You have a botched version of jQuery.  This could happen because someone edited the core file, or a plugin may have overwritten the $ variable.
3. You have JavaScript running before the page is fully loaded, and as such, before jQuery is fully loaded.

Please take a look in here for more detail.

[JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2195167/4544510)

Answer (score 0):

just add a slash

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/semantic.min.js"></script>
```