# Integrate jQuery into a electron app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, electron

I'm trying to add jquery functionality to a desktop app written in electron
Using the electron-quick-start repo i'm adding the downloaded jquery file to the `main.html` file like so:

```
<script> require("./jquery.min.js"); </script>
```

or so:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./jquery.min.js');</script>
```

Then in the `index.js` file i'm adding code in the `createWindow` function, since that seems the proper place, but to be honest any place i try gets me the same error more or less.

`mainWindow.$` is `undefined` and the same goes for `BrowserWindow` and `app`

`mainWindow` is defined inside the `createWindow`  function like so:
`mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})`

and BrowserWindow is declared on top of the file like so:
`const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow`

Any idea where i'm going wrong, what declarations i should change/add?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37480521/1061836

Answer (score 19):

While using electron, some additional symbols are also inserted into DOM causing problems. So, you can use jquery as follow

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" onload="window.$ = window.jQuery = module.exports;"></script>
```

Notice the code inside "onload".

Comment: `jQuery requires a window with a document` unfortunately, none of the answers I've found on any website have worked.

Answer (score 9):

When you call `require` inside `index.js`, or the main process, it's looking for the node module. So you'll need to install `jQuery` via npm and save it as a dependency in your apps package.json file.

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Then your `index.js` should theoretically see it just fine using

```
let $ = require('jquery');
mainWindow.$ = $;
```

Refer to the [Node.JS section for installing jQuery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jQuery). This is what Electron uses.

--

**OLD ANSWER**

Inside your `main.html`, just include the JavaScript like you would any traditional JS file.

```
<script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to solve the issue. Besides, i thought the require statement already took care of that. And the issue is with visibility inside the index.js file. If i add a console.log($) statement after the require statement i get what i would expect. It's just that the visibility does not translate to the index.js file

Comment: @omu_negru Sorry I misunderstood what you were asking. I've updated my answer with the steps that should resolve your issue. Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks, but this is causing the app to throw another exception `require(...).jsdom(...).createWindow is not a function`

Comment: @omu_negru Could you share the code of your `index.js`? Not too sure why that would be an error

Comment: @omu_negru also, do you want me asking why you want jQuery available in your main process?

Comment: note, it should be `npm install jquery --save` (lowercase) to get the latest version of jquery

Answer (score 1):

To integrate `jQuery` into your **Electron Application** follow these simple steps
**Step 1:** Run in terminal

```
npm install jquery --save
```

**Step 2:** Add this line to your `angular.json` or `angular-cli.json` file

```
 "build": {
        "options": {
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", //add this line
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
...
...
     }
  }
```

**Step 3:** Finally add this line to your `index.html` file

```
 <!-- Need this for jQuery electron -->
  <!-- Insert this line above script imports  -->
  <script>if (typeof module === 'object') {
    window.module = module;
    module = undefined;
  }</script>

  <!-- Insert this line after script imports -->
  <script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
</head>
```

You can also use this [template](https://github.com/Majed93/angular-electron-bootstrap-jquery)