# executing javascript animation inside electron

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, animation, electron

I am interested in creating man machine interfaces with Electron.  Trying to do a demo with the Star trek life signs monitor.  Found this code that is easily modified to move up and down : http://jsfiddle.net/anex6vmq/

Here is my HTML and Javascript:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    div.a {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: red;
      position: fixed;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body background="startrekbg.png">
  <div class='a'></div>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
      animateDiv();
    });
    function makeNewPosition() {
      // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
      var h = $(window).height() - 500;
      var w = $(window).width() - 500;
      var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
      var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
      //var nw = 777;
      return [nh, nw];
    }
    function animateDiv() {
      var newq = makeNewPosition();
      $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function () {
        animateDiv();
      });

    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js code :

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

let mainWindow

app.on('ready', () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 670,
    width: 995,
    frame: false
  })
  mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/animation.html')
})
```

And my package.json :

```
`{
  "name":    "Sick Bay Scanner by H.A. Hobson",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main":    "main.js"
}`
```

I work mostly with C, PHP and Python.  Have not done much JavaScript, but find Node and Electron very exciting things to learn.  Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What's the error exactly? If it's about jquery - what i suppose -  see this thread how to use it in Electron: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/202/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-electron-framework

Comment: @perty:  Thank you!  The error seems to be :  ReferenceError: $ is not defined.  I have installed jquery and have looked at the site.  No luck as of yet.

Comment: well, doing the same I succeeded with your code (`npm i jquery` and add `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');` in the first line of `<script>` ) _I also removed reference to `startrek_bg.png` but I suppose you have that_

Comment: @perty:  Thanks !  It is working now with the background image.  I am so relieved.  How do give you credit ?

Comment: glad to hear! i'll make an answer you can accept! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right but you use jquery, which requires further operations to make it work in node.js:

- install [`jquery`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery) node module with `npm i jquery` (add `--save` flag to copy dependency to package.json if you plan to deploy it)
- Add this line as the first line in your script

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

---

*Further readings on this topic can be found:*

- https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/202/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-electron-framework
- [Integrate jQuery into a electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37745273/integrate-jquery-into-a-electron-app)