# oauth authorize page when using Electron - LABJS error: jQuery is not defined

Tags: oauth, electron, khan-academy

I'm using the Khan Academy API in an Electron application, I noticed that the login page (/api/auth2/authorize) has the option to login with Facebook or Google but not with Khan Academy account.

There's that error in the devtools

```
Error in LABjs loading: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

How can I get the page to load normally like it does in a browser?

Comment: Can you post the exact URL you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron windows do not load Jquery properly. You can find info on how to load Jquery [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined).

However, it looks as tho you are just loading a website url directly into Electron? I if this is true you should have a look at Electrons [`<webview>` tag](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/web-view-tag/).