# Dollar is not defined

Tags: javascript, electron

I have created a simple website and a corresponding javascript file. When I open the site in any browser, it works fine. The script gets executed and there are no errors.

Then I tried to convert my website to a web-app using Electron. For now I didn't change anything, and added only a package.json and a main.js file, as described in Electron's getting started guide.

When opening the app, I can see my website just fine. But there is alsoan error popping up:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined

This comes from my javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(doStuff, INTERVAL_MS);
});
```

So my question is:
Why did this code work when I run the site directly in the browser?
And why the error when I run it via Electron?

PS:
This how my index.html's head looks like. As you can see jQuery is included.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <!-- Style sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <!-- External libraries -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Internal scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/globals.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/viewModel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/util.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dummyDataProvider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/switcher.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: May be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: How do you include jQuery?

Comment: Your page hasn't loaded jQuery yet

Comment: jQuery is included first, before the script that then causes the $-error. I've added the relevant code section.

Comment: So what is the stuff that comes from Electron? Which one of those script files is your original JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

Append your `index.html` with the following script and make sure the path is correct for your case:

```html
<script>
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./js/libs/jquery-2.2.0.min.js');
</script>
```