# jquery not loading when it is included before other javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Electron Boilerplate</title>

    <link href="stylesheets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin v2.0</a>
      </div>
    ...



    </nav>
  </div>
    <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="helpers/context_menu.js"></script>
    <script src="helpers/external_links.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently console gives me the following three errors:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery  (bootstrap.min.js:16)
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined        (metisMenu.min.js:9)
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined  (sb-admin-2.js:6)

I've searched the net and I couldn't find a solution that fits my problem. I tried moving `jquery.min.js` to the header and changing the source of jquery to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js. Both options do not work. I think it is probably because jquery is getting loaded after other javascript files are loaded. How can I fix this?

UPDATE:
This is my folder structure:

[image]

vendor has:
[image]

app.html is here:

[image]

I tried typing `jQuery.fn.jquery` and `jQuery().jquery` in the console. Both gave me `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…).` So it seems like jQuery is not loaded at all.

Comment: see console whether any 404 error?

Comment: no I don't see any 404 errors

Comment: make sure also you did not add jquery twice

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? You will need to use a supported version, jQuery versions 1.9.1 - 3 should be supported. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/bower.json

Comment: $ is not defined and jQuery is not defined is the same error. $ is a shorthand for the jQuery object. - Bootstrap requiring the jQuery object is clear as well... unclear why it doesn't find it though... strange

Comment: Is jQuery loaded *after* other scripts as you're assuming, or it's not loaded at all? Have verified that jQuery is defined in console?

Comment: Going through your error you should place jquery before loading bootstrap

Comment: check the path of jQuery.

Comment: @varimax show your dir structure please

Comment: Either your folder struture path issue or you are using older version of path

Comment: @varimax post your console->network tab result screen shot.

Comment: Note, he says https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js didn't work either, and obvioulsy on that one the path is correct.

Comment: Bootstrap must be dependent on older version of jQuery i.e. 3.1.1 thus you are getting the error

Comment: @Julix not if a cached version was loaded without the updated path.

Comment: According to bootstrap's ```bower.json```, you need a version >= 1.9.1 and <= 3. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/bower.json

Comment: I had copied your html and loaded with jquery source you mentioned it works absolutely fine. No problem at all.

Comment: Do this load ypur web page using ctrl+F5 then view source and click on each source links of script tags and see if you get a 404 somewhere.

Comment: @Raju I am building an electron app. Is there a way to do what you said?

Comment: @varimax just follow the steps I mentioned above.

Comment: hmm... when I try to click on those sources in console it doesn't redirect me anywhere. It just prompts me to rename the sources

Comment: not in console you have to click them on view source page

Comment: I had been inspecting app.html by running the entire project as electron. When I open just app.html itself on Chrome it actually does not give me the jQuery not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like jQuery was loaded into an isolated scope in electron. 
You can insert this script **before** all script imports

```
<script>
if (typeof module === 'object') {
    window.module = module; 
    module = undefined;
}
</script>
```

This should work for browser and electron

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks, I found a similar answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: great. thank you it work for ...i just added this befor my jquery script.. and it works..