# Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function in nodejs(electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I installed the gentelella template from npm package manager and i'm trying to include the PNotify script like this(css is included at the top):

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="node_modules/gentelella/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- PNotify -->
<script src="node_modules/gentelella/vendors/pnotify/dist/pnotify.js"></script>
```

However when i execute the application i get this error:

```
pnotify.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: b is not a function
at q (pnotify.js:6)
at pnotify.js:31
at pnotify.js:6
at pnotify.js:6
```

But **when i execute the index.html using the browser it works fine**, why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the jquery wasn't loading correctly.

I did this and it worked:

[Electron: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)