# jQuery failed on calling "Slider" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a slider in a html file with [this bootstrap api](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/), but it keeps showing `jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).Slider is not a function TypeError:

```
 $(...).Slider is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///Users/apple/Desktop/pjt/index.html:35:18)
    at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2:30164)
    at k (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2:30478) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2
k @ jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2
jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Slider is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:35)
    at j (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)`
```

I downloaded both js and css files from [here](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/tree/master/dist).

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-slider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

  </head>

  <body>
      <header class="nav-header">
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="left_section">
          <input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="3"/>
<span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal">3</span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="middle_section">
        </div>
        <div class="right_section">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#ex6").Slider(); // I also tried .slider()
       $("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
           $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
       });

   })

   </script>
      </body>


</html>
```

I also tried to use CDN to replace the local js and css but nothing changes

Comment: `slider` not `Slider`

Comment: I tried both but the issue still exists

Comment: I posted an naswer .. Please read it carefully with note

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a [slider documentation](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/) -- You have 2 ways to use it

```
var mySlider = new Slider('#ex6');
```

OR

```
$('#ex6').slider();
```

**Working example using `.slider`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

  </head>

  <body>
      <header class="nav-header">
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="left_section">
          <input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="3"/>
<span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal">3</span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="middle_section">
        </div>
        <div class="right_section">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#ex6').slider();
       $("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
           $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
       });

   })

   </script>
      </body>


</html>
```

**working example using `var myslider = new Slider('#ex6')`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

  </head>

  <body>
      <header class="nav-header">
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="left_section">
          <input id="ex6" type="text" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="3"/>
<span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal">3</span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="middle_section">
        </div>
        <div class="right_section">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.8.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var mySlider = new Slider('#ex6');
       $("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
           $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
       });

   })

   </script>
      </body>


</html>
```

> **Note**: On my examples I used slider [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/bootstrap-slider) so if your code
>   not working with your css , js paths you can use CDN instead or check
>   your paths

Comment: Hi, when I test my code in the browser like what you did, it works fine, but when I copy the same code into an application based on [electron](https://electron.atom.io), it can not recognize the slider function anymore, which is really weird.

Comment: @Deidara glad to hear that .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: you too, it's actually caused by the framework I'm using, I added another answer below yours, but your answer also helps

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I apologize for not writing my question clearly, so the issue is not from the html file, but from the framework that I am working on.

Since I was using [electron](https://electron.atom.io), if you just load the html code, the application can not recognize the js files in the html unless you add the following code before and after your scripts.

```
<!-- Insert this line above script imports  -->
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>

<!-- normal script imports etc  -->
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>    

<!-- Insert this line after script imports -->
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```

Here's the source of the solution on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Write slider instead of  Slider

`$("#ex6").slider();`

And make sure the `bootstrap-slider.js` file is placed in `assets/js/` folder