# jQuery is not defined (within jQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've downloaded jQuery 3.2.1 and jQuery UI 1.12.1 and I am loading them like so:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
```

I get an Uncaught reference error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @
>   jquery-ui.js:14(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.js:16 index.html:165
>   Uncaught TypeError: table.insertRow is not a
>   functionObject.keys.forEach.key @ index.html:165loadResultsIn @
>   index.html:164loadhistory @ index.html:186onload @ index.html:12

I am trying to use this with Electron.  Not really sure what's going on here.  Have tried loading from CDN's also and have the same problem

Comment: might be the placement of your scripts. Isn't your error referring to an error in your index.html? maybe where you try to use jQuery?

Comment: either use latest `jQuery-ui` library or downgrade you main jQuery library to older-one for support of `jQuery` syntax

Comment: @lscmaro I'm not using jQuery yet,  only linking to it!

Comment: @AlivetoDie 1.12.1 is the latest version of jQuery UI. I've tried jQuery 1 - 3 and all cause the same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found solution here:
[Electron: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

```
<!-- Insert this line above script imports  -->
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>

<!-- normal script imports etc  -->
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>    

<!-- Insert this line after script imports -->
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```