# Electron adding JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, electron

I am trying to use bootstrap in my electron app `main.html`

I used this code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="./Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="./Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

but the console raises

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at bootstrap.js:2
    at bootstrap.js:62

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

I searched for solution but all answer are **Call JQuery script before any other script**

and in the code above I called It first and the problem still exists

please help me

I am using [JQuery 1.10.2](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js) and This [Bootstrap style](https://bootswatch.com/paper/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not bootstrap but its jQuery not getting loaded. Please refer to this question to fixed jQuery [Electron: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thank you very much
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37480521/8058050
solved the problem