# Electron - Jquery isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, electron

Hello,
I downloaded electron and installed it on webstorm in order to learn it. I also installed Jquery using the terminal and including in my scripts but jquery isn't working but it is recognized in my code (I haven't got any error).

My code :

```js
const remote = require('electron').remote;
let window = remote.getCurrentWindow();

function exitGame() {
    alert("test");
    $('exit').click(() => {
        alert("closing");
        window.close();
    })
}

exitGame();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Electron Test</title>
    <!-- RESET CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <!-- ADDING CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main_menu.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="exit">Leave the game</div>

    <!-- ADDING JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script>
      // You can also require other files to run in this process
      require('./renderer.js');
      require('./js/jquery.min.js');
      require('./js/main_menu.js');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The jQuery alert is working but the click isn't.
Even if I replace the "exit" id by "body" it's not working...
Can you tell me what's wrong ?
Thank you very much, best regards.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client on node: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#exit', () => {
        alert("closing");
        window.close();
    })`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, made it working by editing the  tag with the code requiere jQuery.
Before Electron's base script tag, I added a tag  with my jQuery. It seems that it wasn't loaded

Answer (score 1):

`exit` is an id and not some element. So you need to use `#` before it.

```
$('#exit').click(() => {
    alert("closing");
    window.close();
})
```

Better way to check jQuer is wokring or not could be:

```
if(!jQuery)
{
   alert("Not working!");
}
```

Comment: I tried using #exit but it's still not working.

The function you said me


    if(!jQuery) {
       alert("Not working!");}

This doesn't pop up any alert so jQuery is working. But the click does not, I can't get the reason why it doesn't

Comment: Try doing `jQuery('#exit').click((`

Comment: This is also not working. It was working on vanilla JS but not on jQuery. Is Electron not compatible with jQuery ?