# jQuery integration in electron

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, electron, integration

I would like to integrate jQuery in my electron project, I need it because I need this code to run

```
$('#link').on('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let $form = $(this),
    $select = $form.find('select');
  links = $select.val();
  if (links.length > 0) {
    for (i in links) {
      link = links[i];
      window.open(link);
    }
  }
});
```

I tried this code to fix it

```
  <script>if (typeof module === 'object') { window.module = module; module = undefined; }</script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>
  <script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```

which is the one that everyone uses, but it doesn't work, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

install it using NPM

```
npm i jquery
```

import it like this

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

then have fun

edit:
check this link [$ is not defined - using jQuery with electron.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283710/is-not-defined-using-jquery-with-electron-js)
you will find a complete example in the answers there

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the fact that electron runs on node, hence `module` is defined and this part of the jQuery source, add jQuery to the `module` and not the `window` object:

```
if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
  // set jQuery in `module`
} else {
  // set jQuery in `window`
}
```

Try installing jQuery with npm and then simply add this script tag:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
```