# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in electron

Tags: jquery, electron

I’m having a jquery issue.

I have a js file that link to some other webpage that includes jquery.
(Ex. window.location=‘https://www.google.com’, by the way I don’t know if google website uses jquery or not)

It works fine inside my internal js file that uses jquery but when I link to new page(external page), I get a Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined error.

How can I import jquery into the external website that I want to show.
Does anyone have ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does that "some other page" use jQuery?

Comment: yes! It uses jQuery.

Comment: Not the same case, but maybe related to this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined