# Bootstrap 4 modal not working in electron

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, electron

Am working with angular 6 and electron 2. so I have a modal which works in browser but not working in electron any idea on how I should go about this?

Comment: Any errors in console? also posting your code would be helpful to find what's wrong.

Comment: Without code no one can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are having problems using jquery in electron.

That problem was already solved here:
[Electron: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined/37480521#37480521)

Load jquery in your index.html before other libraries that have it as dependency

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
```