# $(...).jstree is not a function, using JSTree in Electron js

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron, jstree

I'm building an app in `python` `django` using the `jQuery` and `jsTree`. The app is working the browser properly, but when I create the electron app for my project it's showing that

> $(...).jstree is not a function.

I am getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
    at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/common/reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.5/jstree.min.js:2:146
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.3.5/jstree.min.js:2:175
```

I also included the following script after the jquery CDN link.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            try {
                $ = jQuery = module.exports;
            } catch(e) {}
        </script>
```

Comment: Please provide some code. How you are using it.
Make sure your jstree script after jQuery script.

Comment: @AagamJain, its working in the browser not in the electron js app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer

```
<!-- Insert this line above script imports  -->
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>

<!-- normal script imports etc  -->
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>    

<!-- Insert this line after script imports -->
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```

refer : [Electron: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score -2):

From this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            try {
                $ = jQuery = module.exports;
            } catch(e) {}
        </script>
```

Change this :

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                try {
                    $.jQuery = module.exports;
                } catch(e) {}
            </script>
```

Your function is wrong.

You cannot do `$=jquery="something"`. Hence the error

Comment: No, It can be done only this way `$ = jQuery = module.exports;` and your logic is giving me more errors. @mkyriacou1994