# shown.bs.tab event not firing in electron app

Tags: bootstrap-4, electron, datatables-1.10

While trying to implement the fix for the datatables.net header sizing problem (headers aren't sized to the table body when created in a hidden tab), I discovered that my event listener function is never called when I run the page from within electron (2.0.9).  When I run the same html page within a browser, the event listener runs.  I'm using Bootstrap v4.0.0, and the datatables.net-bs4 npm package (version 1.10.19).

Here is the applicable html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

        <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="../vendor/datatables/DataTables-1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../vendor/datatables/DataTables-1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../vendor/datatables/Plugins/Scroller-1.5.0/js/dataTables.scroller.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="../vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
        <!-- <script src="../vendor/datatables/Plugins-master/pagination/full_numbers_no_ellipses.js"></script> -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/datatables/DataTables-1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/add_edit_group_window.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/datatables/DataTables-1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/datatables/Plugins/Scroller-1.5.0/css/scroller.bootstrap.css">

        <!-- Icon Library-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendor/datatables/DataTables-1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
            <div class="container card main">
                <br>
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-pills" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" id="tab-1" href="#tab-1-settings">Tab1 Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-tab-settings" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" id="tab-2" href="#tab-2-settings">Tab2 Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-tab-settings" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" id="tab-3" href="#tab-3-settings">Tab3 Settings</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-tab-settings" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#tab-4-settings">Tab4 Settings</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content">

                    <!-- tab-1 Settings -->
                    <div id="tab-1-settings" class="container-fluid tab-pane active"><br>
                        <br>
                        stuff
                    </div>

                    <!-- tab-2 settings -->
                    <div id="tab-2-settings" class="container-fluid tab-pane fade table-responsive"><br>
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" id="tab2Tbl" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Table2</th>
                                    <th>Col2</th>
                                    <th>Col3</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tab-2-body-tab">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <!-- tab-3 settings -->
                    <div id="tab-3-settings" class="container tab-pane fade  table-responsive"><br>
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" id="tab3Tbl" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Table3</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Col2</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Col3</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Col4/th>
                                    <th scope="col">Col5</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tab-3-body-tab">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <!-- tab-4-settings -->
                    <div id="tab-4-settings" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                        <h3>tab-4-settings</h3>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container card" style="text-align: right;">
                <br>
                <p><button class="btn" id="submitButton" type="button" disabled data-toggle="tooltip">Add New</button>
                <button class="btn" id="cancelButton" type="button">Cancel</button></p>
            </div>
    </body>
    <script src="page.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("setting up event for bootstrap");
    console.log(navigator.appName);

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        console.log('show - after the new tab has been shown');
    });
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
        console.log('show - before the new tab has been shown');
    });
});

</script>
```

In addition, I also had put in another event listener in the $(document).ready function,

```js
$('#tab-2').click(function (e) {
    console.log("clicking tab-2");
    e.preventDefault();
    // $(this).tab('show');
    console.log($(this));
    console.log($(this).tab);
    console.log($($.fn.dataTable.tables( true ) ));
    $('.table').css('width', '100%');
    $('.dataTables_scrollHeadInner').css('width', '100%');
    let x = $('#tab-2').find("th");

    console.log(x[0]);
    console.log($(x[0]));
    console.log($(x[0]).css("width"));
    console.log($($.fn.dataTable.tables( true ) ));
    console.log($($.fn.dataTable.tables( true ) ).DataTable());

});
```

This gets called when I click on the tab, and the values are there for all but the fn.dataTable log lines.  The console.log for fn.dataTable.tables show an empty array, and a _Api object that appears to be empty of data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: And see this https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11082

Comment: See my edit above.  The click event is firing when I click the tab.  Also, I am doing the require('jquery') in the included js script ("page.js")

Comment: Another oddity.  When I register the shown.bs.tab event, and view the event listeners in the dev tools window, I see the event "shown" for those elements, but not "shown.bs.tab".I tried hacking the bootstrap.js file to use the event "shownbstab" (without dots) and changed my javascript to register the same event name, but the event listener function still did not fire.

Comment: I really dont know anything about electron, I could just ascertain that your markup is right -> http://jsfiddle.net/cy0kx44o/294/ and after googling realize there seem to be some common mistakes. The `*.bs.tab` thing is just a namespace, you should not need to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks.  in jsfiddle (and a browser), the show.bs.tab and shown.bs.tab events do fire, but they do not inside electron

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found the problem.  In the included js file (page.js) I have the statement:

var $ = require('jquery')

I put the document.ready block inside the included js file, and removed the require line.  Now the shown.js.tab event is firing.