# How do i pass javascript variables to electron and manipulate it

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Hi i'm very new to `electron` please bear with me.

**i have a situation like this:**

1. i will get filename from `li`
2. once the `filename` got i want to write it with below code

   ```
   var fs = require('fs');
   fs.writeFile('gotfromjsvariable', 'Hello content!', function (err)
   ```

   {
           if (err) throw err;
             console.log('Saved!');
         });

suppose `gotfromjsvariable` is coming from below code

question is, How do i pass it to electron main.js or same file node.js

```js
$(document).on('click','#files li',function(){
   var gotfromjsvariable = $(this).data('filename');
   // gotfromjsvariable has to be sent a filename to nodejs or electron
   
   /*
  
 var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('gotfromjsvariable', 'Hello content!', function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
              console.log('Saved!');
  });
   
   */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="files">
  <li data-filename="abc.json">abc.json</li>
  <li data-filename="pqr.json">pqr.json</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `gotfromjsvariable` is a variable name. So, you can use it without single quote on the **fs.writeFile()** method

Answer (score 0):

Basically you send messages (data) from Renderer process to Main process by [`ipcRenderer`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer).

However, as the Renderer process also have access to node API your task can be done completely in html. Your fixed code can look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <ul id="files">
        <li data-filename="abc.json">abc.json</li>
        <li data-filename="pqr.json">pqr.json</li>
      </ul>
      <script>
        const fs = require('fs')
        window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
        $(document).on('click','#files', (e) => {
          var gotfromjsvariable = $(e.target).data('filename')
          fs.writeFile(gotfromjsvariable, 'Hello content!', (err) => {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('saved')
          })
        })
      </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

---

For jquery I've used this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32621989/2550156