# Electron Jquery click not working with table elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

For some reason clicking with Jquery doesn't work with table `TD` elements in Electron. It works fine in a Chrome browser but not as an Electron app. All other elements are fine like `div, li, span, button` etc...only `td` doesn't work.

```
<td class="td">Test</td>

 $('.td').click(function (e) {
   console.log('test');
 });
```

Any ideas why this is?

Electron version 5.0.1.

Chromium version 73.0.3683.121

Comment: This may help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37480521/1273882

Comment: @Ankush Jain Isn't that about Jquery not working at all in Electron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's becuse `td` tag should be on real table (should have `tr` and `table` parent tags). like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td">Test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td">Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Chrome will create `tr` tag for `td` tags if they are outside `tr`. but electron doesn't.

Comment: You're right it does work like that, the problem seems to actually be with elements created by electron. Even a simple button does not work if it's created with a jquery function.