# Why does Select2 not override the normal select boxes in Electron?

Tags: electron, jquery-select2

Here is my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <select id="test">
  <option value="" selected=hidden>Select Product</option>
  <option></option>
 </select>
</body>
<script>
 window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
 require('select2')();

 $(document).ready(function(){
  let contents = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"];

  $("#test").select2({
   data:contents
  });
 });
</script>
</html>
```

I have installed both jquery and select2 as node modules. Jquery seems to work just fine. Here are photos of the electron output:

[Two dropdowns appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL2bf.png)
[Both can be interacted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOCi4.png)

Am I missing something simple?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: Can you try loading select2 externally through a url? Instead of through a node module.

Comment: @Joshua I was hoping to be able to use it offline. However, using a CDN just for Select2 does work. At least I now know jQuery probably wasn't the problem.

Comment: Cool, what you can do then is download the `.js` file from the CDN and put it in the same folder as your `.html` file, then you can include it like: `<script src="/select2.min.js"></script>`. And that way it'll work offline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install `select2` manually insead of using NPM. This way you can use `select2` offline.

1. Download the latest release of `select2` (`.zip`) from: https://github.com/select2/select2/tags
2. Unzip the downloaded `.zip` and copy the necessary files from `/dist`.
3. Include these files in your `.html` file like:

```
<link href="path/to/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="path/to/select2.min.js"></script>
```

All done! Now `select2` will work offline.

[More details](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation#manual-installation)