# Electron pop up window ($ is not defined); No error in console log

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, electron

In a Nutshell: I am implementing a single-page website using Electron and encountered the common issue of jQuery not being globally accessible. So I simplified the problem by using the quick start example in the following in order to figure it out, but I cannot make sense of it.

As you can see, I have simply added the following code to the end of my `main.js` file to check if the issue is resolved:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("hi");
});
```

This is the complete code of my `main.js` file:

```js
// main.js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

function createWindow() {
    // Create the browser window.
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"),
        nodeIntegration: true,

        webSecurity: true,
    },
    });

    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadFile("index.html");

    // Open the DevTools.
    // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();

    app.on("activate", function () {
    // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
    // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
    });
});

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on("window-all-closed", function () {
    // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") app.quit();
});

// In this file you can include the rest of your app's specific main process
// code. You can also put them in separate files and require them here.

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("hi");
});
```

I am loading the following HTML code into my `BrowserWindow`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->

    <!--This was added otherwise "window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');" will not be executed-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />

    <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using Node.js <span id="node-version"></span>,
    Chromium <span id="chrome-version"></span>,
    and Electron <span id="electron-version"></span>.

    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');</script>
    <script src="./renderer.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Below script is attached to the `BrowserWindow` as a `preload` script as advised by the Electron documentation:

```js
// Preload.js
// All of the Node.js APIs are available in the preload process.
// It has the same sandbox as a Chrome extension.
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(selector);
    if (element) element.innerText = text;
    };

    for (const type of ["chrome", "node", "electron"]) {
    replaceText(`${type}-version`, process.versions[type]);
    }
});
```

Last but not least, this is the `package.json` configuration file of the quick start project:

```
{
    "name": "electron-quick-start",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A minimal Electron application",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron ."
    },
    "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
    "keywords": [
        "Electron",
        "quick",
        "start",
        "tutorial",
        "demo"
    ],
    "author": "GitHub",
    "license": "CC0-1.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^9.0.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "^3.5.1"
    }
}
```

However, each time I run the app, I get the following error prompt:

[image: pop up window]

This error is also shown in my app's Powershell output (I have only redacted the full directory path):

> ```sh
> App threw an error during load
> ReferenceError: $ is not defined
>   at Object.<anonymous> (...directory\0masterproject\main.js:48:1)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1004:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
>   at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
>   at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:738:28)
>   at loadApplicationPackage (...directory\0masterproject\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:109:16)    at Object.<anonymous> (...directory\0masterproject\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:155:9)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1004:10)
> PS ...directory\0masterproject> npm start
> ```

However, when I close this window and check the `BrowserWindow`'s console, I do not see any error, but no "hi" output either.

Before I ran into this issue, I had the problem that `require ()` was not defined, which I have resolved by adding

```html
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before my jQuery code:

```html
<script>window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');</script>
```

I found this solution in [this article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/202/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-electron-framework); I have already tried [this example in Electron's documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/all#i-can-not-use-jqueryrequirejsmeteorangularjs-in-electron) but to no avail.

Please let me know of there is any information missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Yes! For the most part. @AlexanderLeithner is right by stating that I need to get more familiar with the overall electron structure and processes. For now I will have to learn more and come back to this issue later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing your [main and renderer processes](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model). With Electron, all code that is responsible for your UI, i.e. the JavaScript attached to the HTML loaded in the `BrowserWindow`s run in renderer processes, all other code, which, for example, is responsible for opening the windows or for setting up you `app` runs in the main process.

In this main process, you cannot use DOM-specific globals because the main process is a pure Node.js thing. What you wanted to do with jQuery, i.e.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log("hi");
});
```

won't work nonetheless, because `document` is not defined in the main process. Also, the main process' environment is detached from your renderer process' (which is why you must use IPC to communicate between them) and thus `$` is not defined in your `main.js` because you define it in the renderer HTML.

If you instead put the following at the end of your HTML (or even your `renderer.js` you include at the very end of your HTML) file, you might get the result you were looking for:

```html
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
    const $ = window.jQuery;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("hi");
    });
</script>
<script src="./renderer.js"></script>
```

After all, I'd suggest to familiarise yourself with the Electron architecture by digging into Electron's documentation, such as [this article](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture) because there is no much more that can go wrong when not familiar with the main/renderer design principle which can be easily fixed by simply understanding this design.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!! I will take your advise and learn more about electron. It is already very helpful was you wrote, because I was not familiar with most of the terms you mentioned to decribe my problem.