# The html in Node.js application can not load jquery correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, networking

my friends. I am writing an simple app in electron framework-- **basic just Node.js as end and HTML as front.**

I try to use jquery lib in my html page like this :

`$(document).ready(function(){})`

The werid part is, if I run this HTML directly in browser, the jquery could work.But when I use it as a part of my electron project,ego:dependency. The jquery could not work.I have tried both use external source and local file.

I get a error like this:
*Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined*

And in the dev tool: **the source panel could show the domain and the file I want to use.**
But the network panel did not show correspond information as  while open in browser does.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

`npm install jquery` in your project then import jquery as `$`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tomorrow, it is pretty late in my region.