# JQuery not working with electron framework

Tags: html, jquery, node.js, npm, electron

I'm trying to using jquery with electron framework using electron fiddle.
However jquery seems not working properly and animation are not executed.
The example is the following: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation1

**main.js**

```js
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window

const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  // Open the DevTools.
  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow)

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  // On OS X it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js');</script>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({left: '250px'});
  });
});
</script> 

  </head>
  <body>
    
<button>Start Animation</button>

<div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>

<script>
  // You can also require other files to run in this process
  require('./renderer.js')
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Nothing happens once clicked on the button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: @Joshua nope, the answer below is the right one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you'd install electron via `npm install jquery` to your `node_modules` folder and require it inside your `renderer.js`. So:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

belongs inside the renderer.js. This way you have it locally and yiu are not depndant on an external CDN anymore.

Comment: Yeah but it needs also to be added in index.html:
<script>
  window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
 </script>

Comment: No, it does not. I use jquery in nearly every project - there is no need to add it to your html files. Your `renderer.js` is required in the index.html and renderer.js requires jquery. (to be save I always require it in the very first line)

Comment: but I don't know for what reason if I don't add it in index, jquery doesn't work.

Comment: I found the error. It works the way I told you, but of course you have to move the `<script></script>` part with the `document ready` beneath the require of `renderer.js`. Tried it. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Well in 2022. This was how I got it working.

Install JQuery

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Use the `script` tag to add jquery to your `index.html` file.
The `src` should be the path to jquery in your `node_modules` folder

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now JQuery would be available as `$` in your renderer process (`renderer.js` file)