# jQuery is not defined when trying to embed a video in electronJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

**Overview**
I am trying to embed a video in my electron app. My main.js script loads a page called index.html. index.htm then sources a scripts called app.js for the functionality of the page. In app.js, I a few embedded videos as so

```
for (let vid of shuffledVideos){
                try{
                    let cuurVid = await Video.findById(vid);
                    console.log(cuurVid)
            
                    let d = document.createElement('div');
                    d.classList.add("videoCard")
                    mediaDisp.append(d)
            
                    let i = document.createElement("iframe");
                    i.setAttribute("src", cuurVid.link)
                    i.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "allowfullscreen")
                    i.setAttribute("width", "650")
                    i.setAttribute("height", "490")
                    i.setAttribute("frameborder", "0")
                    i.setAttribute("scrolling", "no")
                    d.append(i)
                }
                catch{
                    console.log(`Failed to create video: ${vid}.`)
                }
            }
```

When it runs I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined at embed-en.js?2740:222". I've tried a few things listed below.

**Things I've Tried**

I've tried the things in this post: [Electron: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined) but maybe I'm just doing them wrong. At the end of my body tag in index.html, I tried doing this

```
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
    <script>
        require("../js/renderer.js")
    </script>

    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
```

as well this

```
    <script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./../js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        require("../js/renderer.js")
    </script>
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
    <script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```

and both output the same error. I also tried npm installing jQuery and requiring it at the top of app.js by doing

```
const jQuery= require("jquery")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downgrading electron to before nodeintegration was set to false by default.