# Electron.js does not load jQuery due to security policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-security-policy

I am trying to load jQuery in Electron (v. 16.0.0), but I get this error:

[image: jQuery error]

Inside the `head` element I have included this line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self';">
```

Also, inside the `body` element, I am trying to load jQuery like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have tried so many ways to find a solution for this, but to no avail. Previously, I also tried to load jQuery like this, but it gave me a similar error, shown below:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./libraries/jQuery/jquery.min.js');</script>
```

[image: jQuery Error]

Answers to [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined/37480521) did not work for me either. What should I do?

Comment: look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621988/electron-jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: Your CSP header should be `script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src

Comment: @MalikJunaidRamzan  I clarified in my post that I have already looked at that link

Comment: @Liam That did not work for me either. This is the error I got: `Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' code.jquery.com". ...`

Comment: Needs `https`. You should really read the link I posted. It's all explained there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason Electron, or any other Web browser that implements [Content Security Policy](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/), for that matter, would *correctly refuse* to load a script from an arbitrary *origin* (URL), or even an "inline" script (e.g. script text inside a `script` element), is because your security policy is explicitly specified to *deny* such attempts, with that `meta` element you said you added:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self';">
```

Why did you add it? Was it there by someone else's hand? Why is it there? It's the reason why Electron denies loading of the scripts in question.

The value of the `content` attribute above, consisting of a single policy "directive" `script-src 'self';`, has the effect of instructing Electron to *only* permit loading scripts (the `script-src` part of the directive) from the *same* origin (the `'self'` part) as that of the document containing the `meta` element.

An origin is determined by the [scheme and authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) of the URL, nothing more and nothing less. This means a document served over HTTPS by `code.jquery.com` is considered to have a different origin than either one of the following:

- A document served over HTTP from `code.jquery.com` (different scheme, same authority)
- A document served over HTTPS from `www.jquery.com` or `jquery.com` (same scheme, different authority)

Importantly, `'self'` also effectively excludes *inline* scripts -- these always have each their own *distinct* origin that matches no other origin, not even that of another inline script. This is in part because a script may modify the document, including adding a `script` element with arbitrary inline content or altering the body of another inline script. To allow inline scripts, the additional directive argument `unsafe-inline` is required.

Rounding back to your use case, you yourself prohibit loading of scripts from the kind of locations you then attempt to use, with that `meta` element of yours.

I advise you to learn how [the Content Security Policy mechanism works](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/), so you can understand the error in your use case. As it is, you will have to decide whether you want to allow loading of scripts from domains (authorities) like "code.jquery.com", or whether, for example, you will only want to allow loading scripts from your (first-party) website, which in turn will probably necessitate you installing a copy of the JQuery library to be served by your website. You will also have to decide if you want to allow "inline" scripts on your site, if necessary.

The CSP mechanism itself is very useful, don't shy away from it, it's there for a reason -- to help you prevent abuse of your site users by malicious scripts loaded by other malicious scripts or mechanisms. Once you understand better what it does, I think you'll appreciate it. But first you need to learn to use it correctly, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues because of jQuery:

1. `script-src 'self'` does not allow to load script from `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js`, that's why you observe *Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'...* error.
   You have to adjust your CSP at least as `script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com;`.
2. After page loads, the jQuery pick up all scripts having `$()` and place them into one inline script in the `<head>` section. That's why you observe *Refused to execute inline script ...* error.
   This inline script can be resolved with either `'unsafe-inline'` or `'unsafe-eval'` or `'nonce-value'`(for jQuery > 3.4).

Allowing `'unsafe-inline'` is a very harmful advice, since such CSP will not protect against XSS at all (https://youtu.be/zlH_bBQMgkc?t=717).

Also Electron does not have the technical ability to refresh the 'nonce' value.

Therefore, the most secure CSP you can do is:

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://code.jquery.com;
```

or much better:

```
default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://code.jquery.com;
```

Note: Contrary to a common misconception, `'self'` does not mean the *Same Origin Policy*, CSP interprets `'self'` much more broadly.